# Why using oAuth2 refresh token is more secure then regenerate an access_token?

Tags: authentication, oauth, rest, token, oauth2

I'm implementing an oAuth2 authentification to secure my REST Api.
As I am implementing oAuth2, I need to generate an `access_token` which will give me a temporary access to my REST datas.
To do it, I simply send an HTTP request with an `id` and a `secret`, which returns an `access_token` and a `refresh_token`. That is the first time I am implementing an oAuth2, and I did some research about what `access_token` and `refresh_token` are. 
It looks like everybody says that the **`refresh_token` must be stored securely**, because it allows you to regenerate an `access_token`. From what I understood, refresh tokens are long-lived, while acces token expires fast, and don't need as much as security as refresh token does, because it expires fast. I am able to use that `refresh_token` to get a new `access_token`, using the same `id` and the same `secret` I use to generate my first `access_token`.
**My questions are** :

1. Why do we use refresh tokens if they need to much security, while we could just regenerate an access each time it expires?
2. It is really just all about checking faster the identity of the one who is sending the request?

*I apologies if I am not asking in the right StackExchange site.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is for user convenience. Having to enter their login credentials too often is annoying to users. Of course, if that is not a concern, you can just not use `refres_token`, which would improve security somewhat. However, users generally dislike logging in often and forcing them to may cause them to do something insecure, such as storing password in browser or disabling 2FA, hence the use of `refres_token`.